# Magento + Phoenix Cash On Delivery + automatic invoices == Invoice totals wrong

Tags: magento, invoice

I'm running Magento 1.8.1.0 (patched SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-1533, SUPEE-5994, SUPEE-6285) on a LAMP stack enviroment.
I've installed the [Phoenix COD extension](https://github.com/PHOENIX-MEDIA/Magento-CashOnDelivery) (v. 1.0.8).
In my development enviroment *cache is disabled*.

I've implemented a module for *automatically create invoices* according to the kind of payment method (COD, PayPal, Credit Card, etc). When a COD order is generated the order totals are correct, but **in invoice's totals the COD fee doesn't appear**.

### Autoinvoice Module

this is the /etc/modules/ file of my module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_Autoinvoice>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Sales />
                <Phoenix_CashOnDelivery />
            </depends>
        </MyCompany_Autoinvoice>
    </modules>
</config>
```

I've created an observer function on the `sales_order_save_after` event

```
public function salesSaveAfter( $event ) {
    $order               = $event->getOrder();
    $payment_method_code = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();

    $is_Paypal = ( strpos( $payment_method_code, 'paypal' ) !== false ) ? true : false;
    $is_Xpay   = ( strpos( $payment_method_code, 'xpay' ) !== false ) ? true : false;
    $is_Cod    = ( strpos( $payment_method_code, 'cashondelivery' ) !== false ) ? true : false;

    if ( $order->canInvoice() && ( $is_Paypal || $is_Xpay || $is_Cod ) ) {
        $invoice = Mage::getModel( 'sales/service_order', $order )->prepareInvoice();
        if ( ! $invoice->getTotalQty() ) {
            Mage::throwException( $this->__( 'Cannot create an invoice without products.' ) );

            return;
        }

        $invoice->register();
        $transactionSave = Mage::getModel( 'core/resource_transaction' )
                               ->addObject( $invoice )
                               ->addObject( $invoice->getOrder() );
        $transactionSave->save();
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

### Some more notes

Has you can see my module depends on Phoenix_CacheOnDelivery so this function should be triggered after any observer's function.

If I manually generate the invoice everything work fine.

If I programmatically launch a script to generate the second invoice (for one order with the first invoice without the COD fee), the invoice is generated only with the COD fee: so everything fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution myself!

**The problem:** Phoenix_CashOnDelivery add the COD fees by attaching to the event `sales_order_payment_place_end` that came after the `sales_order_save_after` so in the order they was set to 0 at the invoice generation time.

**The solution:** Simply change the event to listen in `sales_order_place_after`.

Plus, the `sales_order_save_after` is called many more times needed, so the code it's optimized! Yay!

I hope this could be useful for someone out there.